# Magento 2 Cloud Docker SSL certificate hostname change

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.4, docker, cloud-docker

I am using setup my local Cloud Docker https://devdocs.magento.com/cloud/docker/docker-development.html

local hostname set - test.test

To configure the custom host and port, add the host and port options to the build:compose command.

`./vendor/bin/ece-docker build:compose --host=test.test --port=80`

Still SSL certificate showing default **magento2.docker** on browser. How to change SSL certificate name as host. needed  to DNS- test.test

Please let me know how change certificate name in magento2 docker cloud deploying into localhost.

Thanks;
HP

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using the latest version of Magento2, Navigate to `[MAGENTO_ROOT]/vendor/magento/magento-cloud-docker/images/nginx/[NGINX_VERSION]/Dockerfile` and look for the code

`RUN openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -sha256 -days 730 -nodes \ -keyout /etc/nginx/ssl/magento.key -out /etc/nginx/ssl/magento.crt \ -subj "/C=US/ST=TX/L=Austin/O=Adobe Commerce/OU=Cloud Docker/CN=magento2.docker" \ -addext "subjectAltName=DNS:magento2.docker,DNS:www.magento2.docker"`

Here you can change the domain name for your SSL Certificate `DNS:www.magento2.docker`

In my case its the path to Dockerfile is
`[MAGENTO_ROOT]/vendor/magento/magento-cloud-docker/images/nginx/1.19/Dockerfile`